# GetElements only from parrent span

Tags: c#, selenium

I have list of items from shopping site. Some items have span style=".." and some are without style.I need text value only from spans that are without style="font-size:11px... So only 30 USD and 60 USD in this case.

```
    <span class="item_price"> <span style="font-size:11px;color:#d00;text-decoration:line-through">50 USD</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
30 USD </span>                      
</div>
<span class="item_price">
60 USD</span>
```

Following code returns all text values from from same class:

```
  IList<IWebElement> prices = driver.FindElements((By.ClassName("item_price")));

        foreach (var correctPrice in prices)
        {
            { Console.Write(correctPrice.Text); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't because the SPAN with `style` is inside `span.item_price` so when you do `.Text` on the outer SPAN, you will get the text from the inner SPAN also. You can grab `span.item_price` and then loop through all the contained elements and remove their `.Text` from the original string.

```
static string RemoveChildText(IWebElement parent)
{
    string text = parent.Text;
    foreach (IWebElement e in parent.FindElements(By.CssSelector("*")))
    {
        text = text.Replace(e.Text, "");
    }

    return text.Trim();
}
```

and then call it like

```
IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> prices = Driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("span.item_price"));
Console.WriteLine(RemoveChildText(prices.ElementAt(0)));
Console.WriteLine(RemoveChildText(prices.ElementAt(1)));
```

I tested this on the HTML you posted and it returned

```
30 USD
60 USD
```

Comment: This will do just fine for the question

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve that using xpath, something like this

```
IList<IWebElement> prices = driver.FindElements(By.Xpath("//span[@class='item_price' and not(span[contains(@style,'font-size')])]"));

        foreach (var correctPrice in prices)
        {
            { Console.Write(correctPrice.Text); }
```

this means, you are looking for span without child span with some criteria

Comment: yes, correct, having relook at the html provided, I thought by briefly viewing the html there are three span with class item_price